# How can I prevent multiple calls from an event listener in a Vue Js Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am calling a specific function on the event listener like this.

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("message", this.call);   },

methods: {
    call(e){
       if (e.data === "test"){
          this.call2()
       }
    }
    call2(){
       console.log("called call2")
    }
}
```

on the first try, `call2` is called once. But on the second try, `call2` is called twice and will display "called call2" twice on the console. And so on. for every try, it will just add to the number of times `call2` is being called in a single action. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always remove event listeners in the `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook to prevent leaking listeners.

```
//Add the event listener
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("message", this.call);   
},

//Remove the event listener
beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("message", this.call);   
},
```

Have a look at the Vue lifecycle for reference:

[image]